# Jquery 1 Click Hide and Show left to Right

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I would like my jQuery script one click hide and show, when DIV it hide the link show the word *SHOW*, and when it Show the link show the Word *HIDE*.

Please can you look for me.

Best Regards.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hide').click(function(e) {
        $('.DIV').delay(500).animate({
            marginLeft: '-100%',
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('#show').click(function(e) {
        $('.DIV') .delay(500) .animate({
            marginLeft: '0%',
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with `toggle` and animate `left`. You need to set `position` to `relative` in order to slide it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="toggleDiv">hide</div>
<div class="test">Some text</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.test {
 position: relative;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#toggleDiv').toggle(function() {
    $('.test').delay(500).animate({
        'opacity': 0,
        'left': '-100%'
    });
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html('show');
        n();
    });
}, function() {
    $('.test').delay(500).animate({
        'opacity': 1,
        'left': '0%'
    });
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html('hide');
        n();
    });
});​
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/dW8Rv/1